# How to update a table with sum of a number based on a specific feild?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I wrote below code but based on my reseacrh, there is no way to use Group by in Update.

My code:

```
update customer
set customer.cust_balance= sum(invoice.inv_amount)
where customer.cust_num=invoice.cust_num
group by invoice.cust_num
```

What I think I should do is something similar below but I am not sure if it is entirely true:

```
update customer
set customer.cust_balance= (select sum(invoice.inv_amount) from invoice
                            where customer.cust_num=invoice.cust_num
                            group by invoice.cust_num)
```

I believe above subquery will not do the correct job. Any advise or help would be appreciated

Comment: tag your dbms please ,also your second query looks ok

Comment: Sure I added it . thank you for reminding me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version would work, but it is better to write it as:

```
update customer
    set cust_balance = (select sum(i.inv_amount)
                        from invoice i
                        where customer.cust_num = i.cust_num
                       );
```

In other words, the correlation clause is sufficient.  You don't also need `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, What will happen if I add group by? will the results remain same as without Group by?

Comment: @mohamadatar yes it does. condition `where customer.cust_num = i.cust_num` already guarantees the records you want and that's enough

Comment: Thank you @eshirvana